# Нужно ли переносить Ограничения доступа к данным в расширение 1С?

Tags: 1с

Мне нужно изменить права в роли. Я создал расширение. Добавил в него нужную роль и справочник, к которому нужно изменить права. Надо убрать доступ на добавление. Вот так выглядит оригинальная роль из конфигуратора:

[image]

В роли в расширении убрал галочку у добавления, но нужно ли переносить значения из `Ограничения доступа к данным`?
Ролей, которые нужно изменить еще очень много. Если ограничения нужно переносить в расширение есть ли какой-нибудь быстрый способ?

Comment: Предполагаю, что не нужно. Но это не точно. Полистайте книгу про расширения.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно точно, что при добавлении Роли в расширение, - *ограничения ТАКЖЕ переносятся* ! Очень часто переносят роль в расширение как раз для того, чтобы убрать ограничения. Поэтому, если у Вас в расширении нет ограничений у Роли, - значит их кто-то убрал.